# Spring finds some beans but not others

Tags: java, spring, jpa

i have a test like this

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserAccountRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;
}
```

the autowiring works

in another file

```
@DataJpaTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
}
```

it fails because of the userservice, the bean is not found. i don't understand why.
when i start the app, there is no such error.
the packages of the test and their respective classes are identical.
how can i find out why the bean does not exist?

Comment: Why did you tag the question with `scala`? The code is in Java (and Spring).

Comment: tough to say without additional context, perhaps a good starting point is to enable debug mode include `logging.level.root=INFO` in your properties. That may point you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is occurring because `@DataJpaTest` does not create all the beans, only those associated with JPA.

From the Spring documentation:

> You can use the @DataJpaTest annotation to test JPA applications. By
> default, it scans for @Entity classes and configures Spring Data JPA
> repositories. If an embedded database is available on the classpath,
> it configures one as well. SQL queries are logged by default by
> setting the spring.jpa.show-sql property to true. This can be disabled
> using the showSql attribute of the annotation.
>
> Regular @Component and @ConfigurationProperties beans are not scanned
> when the @DataJpaTest annotation is used.
> @EnableConfigurationProperties can be used to include
> @ConfigurationProperties beans.

If you want the additional beans, you can use `@SpringBootTest`.